# Unable to use agent parameters in delay block

Tags: delay, anylogic

In my source block/move to block I can use agent parameters to for example tell the agent to move to a specific node by coding the location node as agent.locationnode. But somehow in the delay block I'm not allowed (see image below) to use the agents parameters in the agent location. Is there a way to fix it, or is there another option to create a delay with using agents parameters. What I want is that my agents wait at there current location for a specific uniform distributed time. But when I just use the delay block, my model gives the error that it can not leave the delayblock, since there is no agent location I guess.

[image]

[image: The next error]

Comment: You use moveTo block, move the agent wherever you want. Delay there (without location) and then send them somewhere else. What is the exact error you get? It might be that the next block's capacity is reached and it can't simply move forward

Comment: I've added the image of the error at the post, the error pops up when the first agent wants to leave the delay block and goes to the move to block. When I just delete the delay block out of the model, the model works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is not related to the delay, rather to the source. In delay, you have capacity 1, and the next created agent cannot enter this block. You need to increase the capacities, as mentioned in the error message.

If you click `Forced pushing`, the error message might go away. But it might not be a good solution.

Usually putting a queue (with max capacity) before the delay solves the issue.

Comment: Stupid mistake indeed, increasing the capacity fixed the problem. Thanks!